# how to save google instance setup as docker image?

Tags: docker, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, virtual-machine

I work on VM on google cloud for my Machine learning work.

In order to avoid installing all the libraries and module from scratch every time I create a new VM on GCP or whatever, I want to save the VM that I created on `Google Cloud` and save on `GitHub` as a docker image. So that next time, I would just load it and run it as a docker image and get my VM ready for work.

Is this a straightforward task? Any ideas on how to do that, please?

Comment: No; Docker images and VMs are fundamentally different.

Comment: I know the difference. Excuse my misuse of words. I meant that I just want my setup (libraries and packages) to be saved so that I can install it again on a new VM.

Comment: Docker is not the tool you’re looking for.  Consider an automation tool like Ansible or Chef that can deploy things to a newly-provisioned system in a scripted way, though.

Comment: Your idea is a good one and is one of the big positives of using Docker Containers. However, you are approaching a solution from the wrong direction. Start with Docker and then build your containers to fit the applications and not an entire VM. Most languages hare resource definition files (Python: requirements.txt). This is where you specify the libraries. For apps, you want the bare minimum in your container. Save your container in a registry (Google Container Registry).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Compute Engine instance, it is built from an artifact called an "image".  Google provides some OS images from which you can build.  If you then modify these images by (for example) installing packages or performing other configuration, you can then create a new custom image based upon your current VM state.

The recipe for this task is fully documented within the Compute Engine documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images

Once you have created a custom image, you can instantiate new VM instances from these custom images.